# How do i append a number of svgs each with an id to the body using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

**How do i append a number of svgs each with an id to the body using d3?**

```
<body>
        <svg id="1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="4" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="5" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>
```

This is my first attempt that works for drawing 1 svg:

```
// draw 1 svg 

d3.select("body").append("svg")
                 .attr("width",201)
                 .attr("height",202)
                 .attr("id",202)
```

This is my attempt for drawing multiple svgs given an arbitrary array to draw an svg per element.

```
// my attempt to draw multiple svg - not working

var arr =[10,20,30,40,50]

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
                 .attr("width",201)
                 .attr("height",202)
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return d;})
```

see my [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/dhhw04b8/) here (right click on view and inspect to see Elelemnts tab)

**Note: A bigger question I am working towards in the array would be an array of filenames where I want to put a graph in each svg using the data from each file to feed the graph**

---

### EDIT1

Big thanks to @Cyril answer below:

For my ref.

[case1](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/4Lmr4er7/)

[case2](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/yhs5vn6m/)

[case3](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/gmg4fcbv/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your body already has 4 svgs.

You doing

```
<body>
        <svg id="1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="4" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="5" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>
```

it should have been:

```
<body>

</body>
```

Now in this case the following function will append svg to body:

```
var arr =[10,20,30,40,50]

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
                 .attr("width",201)
                 .attr("height",202)
                 .attr("id",function(d){ return d;})
```

Imagine your html like this

**CASE 1**

```
<body>

</body>
```

Now when you do:

```
d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")//this will return an empty selection as there is no svg.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
// This will associate the data to the selection.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
//this will append 5 new svg to the body as the data arr has 5 elements BUT the selection has no svg.
```

**CASE 2**

Now when your body has 5 svg elements:

```
<body>
        <svg id="1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="4" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="5" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")//this will return 5 svg selection.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
// This will associate the data to the selection.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
//the data arr has 5 elements and the selection has 5 elements so no svg will be appended.
```

**CASE 3**

Now when your body has 3 svg elements:

```
<body>
        <svg id="1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")//this will return 3 svg selection.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
// This will associate the data to the selection.

d3.select("body").selectAll("svg")
                 .data(arr)
                 .enter()
                 .append("svg")
//this will append 2 svg to the body now the data arr has 5 elements and the selection has 3 elements so 2 svg will be appended.
```

And it will look like this:

```
<body>
        <svg id="1" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="2" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="3" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="40" width="200" height="200"></svg>
        <svg id="50" width="200" height="200"></svg>
</body>
```

Hope this clears all your doubts.

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/epenmv2w/)

Comment: I had `<svg>` in the body to show what I wanted. So I just had to delete them and it worked [here](https://jsfiddle.net/HattrickNZ/dhhw04b8/1/).

Comment: your fiddle the svg `id=10` is not created because `id=202` is already there. could you comment on this to help me understand it a bit better?.

Comment: Edited my answer hope it covers all scenarios.